# Does anyone share their opinions?

Tags: discussion

The following moderators are elected as Moderators for the Year 2018.

1. [Amit Bera](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera)
2. [Sander Mangel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel)

These two new moderators are very active and very helpful in their activity of knowledge sharing and on other activities on MSE.

I would like to ask you all users of this community that, Does anyone wants to share their experience and their opinion here about these two moderators?

If anyone wants to share their opinions, Please post as answers without hesitate. Then only the new moderators may have the chance to improve themselves if need.

**The reason to ask you after this much of long time :**

If i ask this at the time of next day to the elected time, Everyone will post the positive and congratulations posts only sure. That's why i asked this time. So, Please post your opinions.

Comment: I think Amit is a great moderator! Not too sure about the other guy tho ;)

Comment: I'm not objective. I do love the initiative. really cool

Comment: @SanderMangel are also great moderator :).

Comment: Nice @Amit Bera bai! Congrats!

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't happy with last years election ... seems REP counts more then activity.

After nearly one year a agree with Amits election, currently he is one of the most active people here.

Sander ... ya, Sander is far less active, BUT always gives useful answers and also **takes the time to write good comments to reviews/and flags.** (thumbs)

A perfect job in quality, but for being moderator 'you' should be more active (imho)

Just compare total actions ...

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera?tab=activity
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel?tab=activity

Or ...

- https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/720995/most-active-users-action-every-x-min

Comment: I totally agree with you sv3n, a moderator is rather someone who is often active with strong skills in Mageno, @Amit Bera he has always been active, even before he is moderator, however Sander Mangel before yes but now it's not the case, of course, he gives good answers, he is courteous But it's not limited to that. I wonder why he introduced himself as candidate if he doesn't have the time or he is busy doing something else ! because he an old user ? having a moderator often absent or not active will not help a Magento stackexchange. too bad !

Answer (score 1):

I am posting my opinion as first answer :

**Amit Bera :**

Amit, Congrats dear firstly.

1. Earlier i am seeing that, Amit is replying quickly to the post whether it belongs to meta or MSE.
2. He is correcting the activity if need also.
3. Always trying to post the answers to the questions in a good way and understandable way.

**Sander Mangel :**

Dear Sander, Congratulations.

1. Coming to Sander, He is more great supporter and pusher to the users.
2. He is responding via answers (my opinion only) as of i seen.
3. If Sander also responds to clear the doubts of users in a clear explanation comments, That will be the more pushing to his activity.

**AMIT & SANDER :**

Earlier, I am seeing that [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius)(For the context, I used this profile) is the very active person and he is participating in the user's activities. Like Marius, You both also please followup the customers on their posts. And please transfer the knowledge than current. Please give the posts in a clear way to the users (As of now good).

I am seeing that Amit is participating more Sander actively.

Comment: Last edit was to remove "thanks" from your own post .... this is bit funny :P PLS dont take it personal! :)